# A better way to loop through lists

Tags: c#

So I have a couple of different lists that I'm trying to process and merge into 1 list.

Below is a snipet of code that I want to see if there was a better way of doing.
The reason why I'm asking is that some of these lists are rather large.  I want to see if there is a more efficient way of doing this.

As you can see I'm looping through a list, and the first thing I'm doing is to check to see if the CompanyId exists in the list.  If it does, then I find item in the list that I'm going to process.

pList is my processign list.  I'm adding the values from my different lists into this list.

**I'm wondering if there is a "better way" of accomplishing the Exist and Find.**

```
    boolean tstFind = false;
    foreach (parseAC item in pACList)
    {
        tstFind = pList.Exists(x => (x.CompanyId == item.key.ToString()));

        if (tstFind == true)
        {
            pItem = pList.Find(x => (x.CompanyId == item.key.ToString()));
            //Processing done here.  pItem gets updated here
            ...
         }
```

Just as a side note, I'm going to be researching a way to use joins to see if that is faster.  But I haven't gotten there yet.  The above code is my first cut at solving this issue and it appears to work.  However, since I have the time I want to see if there is a better way still.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Time Findings:

- My current Find and Exists code takes about **84 minutes** to loop through the 5.5M items in the pACList.
- Using pList.firstOrDefault(x=> x.CompanyId == item.key.ToString()); takes **54 minutes** to loop through 5.5M items in the pACList

Comment: The code you posted doesn't address your end goal - merging lists is very different from checking to see if something exists in the list.  If you have an `else` case which adds to the list if `tstFind == false`, then you ought to add that.  But if there's processing involved with deciding the correct way to merge the lists, then you're not going to be able to optimize it to any great extent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve item with `FirstOrDefault` instead of searching for item two times (first time to define if item exists, and second time to get existing item):

```
var tstFind = pList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyId == item.key.ToString());

if (tstFind != null)
{            
   //Processing done here.  pItem gets updated here        
}
```

Comment: Downvoter, hello. I believe you can explain why Exists and Find is better than FirstOrDefault

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was able to easily modify my code and looped through the list in 30 less minutes!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, use a hashtable so that your algorithm is O(n) instead of O(n*m) which it is right now.

```
var pListByCompanyId = pList.ToDictionary(x => x.CompanyId);
 foreach (parseAC item in pACList)
    {
        if (pListByCompanyId.ContainsKey(item.key.ToString()))
        {
            pItem = pListByCompanyId[item.key.ToString()];
            //Processing done here.  pItem gets updated here
            ...
         }
```

Comment: This code would be more efficient if it used `TryGetValue()` instead of checking for key existence and then subsequently fetching by the same key.

Comment: Ah, it's all O(1). :) No, that's a good point. I just have this aversion to out parameters.

Comment: Two O(1) operations still cost twice as much time as one O(1) operation (in this case, where it's the same operation).  Out parameters have their place, and this is one of them.  Of course if the list is small, the difference will not really matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate though filtered list using linq

```
foreach (parseAC item in pACList.Where(i=>pList.Any(x => (x.CompanyId == i.key.ToString()))))
    {
            pItem = pList.Find(x => (x.CompanyId == item.key.ToString()));
            //Processing done here.  pItem gets updated here
            ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using lists for this type of operation is O(MxN) (M is the count of pACList, N is the count of  pList).  Additionally, you are searching pACList twice.  To avoid that issue, use `pList.FirstOrDefault` as recommended by @lazyberezovsky.

However, if possible I would avoid using lists.  A `Dictionary` indexed by the key you're searching on would greatly improve the lookup time.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a linear search on the list for each item in another list is not efficient for large data sets.  What is preferable is to put the keys into a Table or Dictionary that can be much more efficiently searched to allow you to join the two tables.  You don't even need to code this yourself, what you want is a `Join` operation.  You want to get all of the pairs of items from each sequence that each map to the same key.

Either pull out the implementation of the method below, or change `Foo` and `Bar` to the appropriate types and use it as a method.

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<Bar, Foo>> Merge(IEnumerable<Bar> pACList
    , IEnumerable<Foo> pList)
{
    return pACList.Join(pList, item => item.Key.ToString()
        , item => item.CompanyID.ToString()
            , (a, b) => Tuple.Create(a, b));
}
```

You can use the results of this call to merge the two items together, as they will have the same key.

Internally the method will create a lookup table that allows for efficient searching before actually doing the searching.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert pList to HashSet then query pHashSet.Contains(). Complexity O(N) + O(n)
2. Sort pList on CompanyId and do Array.BinarySearch() = O(N Log N) + O(n * Log N )
3. If Max company id is not prohibitively large, simply create and array of them where item with company id i exists at i-th position. Nothing can be more fast.

where N is size of pList and n is size of pACList

Comment: To make HashSet perform well, the size of allocated array is much larger than actual array size, or else collision occurs. So at times binary search is the best option and for that you need a sorted array.

Comment: Oh. So those were different options. I thought you were saing they were STEPS. Gotcha :)